# MySQLD is using 175% of the cpu

Tags: linux, mysql, mysql-replication, cpu-usage, database-performance

On one of the servers, I have mysqld running as slave DB.

The CPU usage is 175% at the moment used by mysqld.

Here are the results of SHOW PROCESSLIST;

```
+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id       | User        | Host      | db      | Command | Time    | State                                                                       | Info                                                                                                 |
+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   109029 | system user |           | NULL    | Connect | 2346123 | Waiting for master to send event                                            | NULL                                                                                                 |
|   109030 | system user |           | NULL    | Connect |       0 | Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944426 | root        | localhost | NULL    | Query   |       0 | NULL                                                                        | SHOW PROCESSLIST                                                                                     |
| 12944443 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944445 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944463 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944466 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944467 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944469 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944470 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944471 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944476 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944479 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944482 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944484 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944485 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944488 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944490 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944491 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944492 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944493 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944495 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944496 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944498 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944499 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944501 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944502 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Query   |       0 | Sending data                                                                | SELECT DISTINCT(article_id) FROM authors WHERE CONCAT(
                firstname,
          |
| 12944503 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Sleep   |       0 |                                                                             | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 12944504 | mdpipub     | localhost | mdpipub | Query   |       0 | Sending data                                                                | SELECT DISTINCT(article_id) FROM authors WHERE CONCAT(
                firstname,
          |
+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: that might be a show process list now but when the cpu was at 175% the list would be different. Show the recent entries in slow query log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fund the problem. I got an attack on the server by someone executing constantly the search function on the website. I just banned this IP and it is fine at the moment.

Comment: this indicates that you have bigger problems, if someone can DoS your server with a lot of search requests

Comment: That's trouth @thanasisk. Should I add something in the firewall to avoid a certain limit of queries per minute?

Comment: that is a good first step. Second step is to make the search more robust.

Comment: More robust? I mean, the search is robust. The attacker created a search simulation by inserting some search words.

Comment: If he made the same query over and over again, where is caching to save the day?

Comment: The query was not the same but with some random words.

Answer (score 1):

This is because 2 potential heavy SELECT queries are running. The load of all threads is then summed up for the main process and may show more than 100%.